# How to duplicate traffic from an Azure web application for testing purposes

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, web-traffic, traffic-simulation

We have several web applications and apis deployed as azure web applications and we would like to automate database changes testing. We are thinking on replicate incoming http traffic towards another instance of the azure service so we will make sure changes are compatible and we are not breaking anything. We saw [goreplay](https://goreplay.org), but it is mostly targeted to installation in servers, but we are deploying to the cloud. Is there any other option?

Comment: This is something I am currently thinking about doing. Did you find a solution for this since then?